# CakePHP: Cache can write file but not read it (always false)

Tags: cakephp, caching

I am trying to cache something. In my core.php config file, I have this:

```
//short
Cache::config('short', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

// long
Cache::config('long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

in my controller, I have this:

```
$xmlpublist = Cache::read('xmlpublist');

var_dump($xmlpublist);

//if cache is still set, return cache
if($xmlpublist !== false) {
    die('cache A');
    return $xmlpublist;
}

Cache::write('xmlpublist', "test", 'short');
die('cache C');
return $xml;
```

I can see that the file is generated - /path/to/cache/cake_short_xmlpublist

But when I `Cache::read('xmlpublist')`, I always get `bool(false)`. I made sure that I have both read and write access to the cache directory.

**Expectation:**
Get values from the cache.

**Result:**
I get bool(false)

Where could have I gone wrong?

Any reply appreciated ;)

Thanks,
W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling `Cache::read()` you need to include the cache configuration to read from, so in your case `'short'`.  Without that additional parameter you'll be reading from the 'default' config which probably doesn't have the key you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. I have checked http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#CacheEngine::read and there is no 2nd parameter in the documentation.

Comment: I think you were looking at the CacheEngine::read() docs, and not Cache::read(). You want to look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#cache-api